# yarn workspace some-package add some-dep (in workspaces root) vs yarn add some-dep (inside a child workspace)

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Just want to know if there's any difference in outcome of the two situations:

1. running the below command in workspaces root

   `~/workspaces-root$ yarn workspace SOME-PACKAGE add some-dep`
2. running the below command inside the child workspace directory

   `~/workspaces-root/packages/SOME-PACKAGE$ yarn add some-dep`

Comment: I couldn't say there isn't some weird detail difference, but would assume in all normal circumstances they do the same thing. Just note, that the workspace name is the one from its `package.json`, not the folder name. And workspaces have to be configured of course.